# Borrowed value does not live long enough with Arc, thread and channel

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

the target of my code is to send custom `Data` with channel (`std::sync::mpsc::channel`) in the thread. `Data` instance are created by a `Manager` and have a reference on `Manager`.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

struct Manager {}

struct Data<'a> {
    manager: &'a Manager,
}

impl Manager {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }

    fn make(&self) -> Data {
        Data { manager: self }
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for Manager {}

fn main() {
    let manager = Arc::new(Manager::new());
    let (tx, _rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut children = Vec::new();

    for id in 0..2 {        
        let thread_manager = Arc::clone(&manager);
        let thread_tx = tx.clone();

        let child = thread::spawn(move || {
            let msg = thread_manager.make();
            thread_tx.send(msg).unwrap();
            println!("thread {} finished", id);
        });
        children.push(child);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28ec00e669dec5c33ee127e2fbca2136)

And i have an error

```
error[E0597]: `thread_manager` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:36:23
   |
33 |         let thread_tx = tx.clone();
   |             --------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `thread_tx`
...
36 |             let msg = thread_manager.make();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
37 |             thread_tx.send(msg).unwrap();
   |             ------------------- argument requires that `thread_manager` is borrowed for `'1`
38 |             println!("thread {} finished", id);
39 |         });
   |         - `thread_manager` dropped here while still borrowed
```

But i don't understand :

1. `let manager = Arc::new(Manager::new());`  create an instance of `Manager` with ref counter
2. `let thread_manager = Arc::clone(&manager);` increase by 1 ref counter but it is the same `Manager`instance
3. `let msg = thread_manager.make();` create a `Data` with a reference on `Manager`

For me, msg could have same lifetime as manager.

where am I wrong ?

Thanks
Etienne

Answer (score 1):

> For me, msg could have same lifetime as manager.

Yes. That means `msg` lives as long as the enclosing function does:

```rust
let child = thread::spawn(move || {
    // <— thread_manager moved into and owned by the function
    let msg = thread_manager.make();
    thread_tx.send(msg).unwrap();
    println!("thread {} finished", id);
    // <— thread_manager is dropped here so `msg` becomes invalid
});
```

there's no telling when the message will actually be received / used, but it'll likely be after the thread has died. And rustc can't assume any other instance of the manager will remain alive at this point, so it has to assume it'll be left with a dangling reference.

Why doesn't `msg` just use an `Arc<Manager>`, or even a `Weak<Manager>`? (though the latter doesn't seem like a great idea here).

You might be able to do something along those lines of what you're attempting (without even `Arc` I believe) using *scoped threads*, but the stdlib's are not scoped, as far as the compiler is concerned there is no lifetime relationship between the caller and contents of a `spawn` call, they live *completely independent* lives, and can run and stop in any order (even if you use `join`). So the reasoning about thread-bound lifetimes is completely local.

Comment: {quote}there's no telling when the message will actually be received / used, but it'll likely be after the thread has died. {quote} it is the smallest extract you could add ```    for _ in 0..2 {
        rx.recv().unwrap();
        println!("receive a msg");
    }

    for child in children {
        child.join().unwrap();
    }
``` but you have same problem

Comment: ```And rustc can't assume any other instance of the manager will remain alive at this point, so it has to assume it'll be left with a dangling reference.``` it is wrong thread_manager died at the end of thread scope but manager is always alive and manager and thread_manager it the same object... it is wrong ?

Comment: i don't sure to understand your last section (without Arc compile failed) because object is used in a thread... it is possible to manually add lifetime relationship ?

Comment: @VaillantEtienne you know this but the compiler has no way to, so its reference is based *solely* on the lifetime of the Arc it got created from. Doesn't matter that the original record may be kept alive by something else. And as I said since the stdlib's threads are not *scoped* join won't do anything, the compiler doesn't understand the concept at all.

Comment: @VaillantEtienne no it's not possible to "manually add lifetime relationship", lifetimes are a way to prove things to the compiler, but these things have to actually exist. This is what [crossbeam's scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.0/crossbeam/thread/index.html) do: they're expressed such that they're always nested within the spawning function *and the compiler understands that*. This means they can just borrow data from their lexical parent as long as that data is `Sync`.